# The command "chmod +x IntuneMAMConfigurator" exited with code 1" Error on Visual studio Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, intune

I am using Intune Mam Package in my Xamarin.iOS Application.
I am facing this issue on my visual studio Mac. I have latest VS (8.10.9), XCode(13) and Mac OS(11.6).
Not able to find solution to this.

Please see below complete error

The command "chmod +x /Users/moeejtamboli/Projects/Live/hsemobile/packages/Microsoft.Intune.MAM.Xamarin.iOS.11.0.13/build/xamarinios10/IntuneMAMConfigurator" exited with code 1.

Comment: Does IntuneMAMConfigurator exist?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Intune.MAM.Xamarin.iOS (14.3.5). I am not aware of IntuneMAMConfigurator. May be package is using that internally.

Comment: More debugging data needed, sadly.  The full backtrace as shown.  Something is trying to make something executable and failing.